# Load data from MySQL in iOS app

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c

Good morning,

How can I load a MySQL query result into a UILabel in my iOS app? I need to display the name of the user, the followers and also the profile image. How can I do that?

I have created the storyboard with the UILabels and the UIImageView but now I need to load the data from my MySQL database and I'm a little bit lost.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get data with JSON.

```
NSMutableURLRequest * requestTransfer;
NSString *strUrl = @"www.yoursite.com/Mobile/GetUser";
requestTransfer = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]
                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
[requestTransfer setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[requestTransfer setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSHTTPURLResponse   * response;
NSError* error = nil;
response = nil;

NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestTransfer returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSDictionary *dicUsers = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

You can use dictionary like that.

```
NSString* strID = [dictionary objectForKey:@"UserID"];
NSString* strName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"UserName"];
NSString* strLink = [dictionary objectForKey:@"ImageLink"];
yourlabel.text = strName;
```

Comment: Thanks Yusuf, can you show me an example? I know some PHP and MySQL but I'm not an expert of JSON and Xcode...! For example: How can I load a UILabel? That UILabel is a cell in a row from my database user. Much appreciated for your help.

Comment: Thanks Yusuf, I'm going to try with your code. The only thing that I don't understand is how can I send the MySQL query trough a JSON and then recieve that data...! Can you tell me how?

Comment: I don't know php. "www.yoursite.com/Mobile/GetUser" u must make a link like that and that must return a user. This is an example http://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld

Comment: Does anyone know how to do that? Because I'm lost at this point Yusuf.

Comment: Thanks Yusuf, I'm going to try with that.